# Portfolio Optimization in R - Unable to add optimization objectives

Tags: optimization, portfolio

I am unable to add multiple objective while optimizing portfolio in R

Maximize quadratic utility. i.e., maxret and minvar

`qu <- add.objective(portfolio=portf, type="return", name="mean")`

---

```
qu <- add.objective(portfolio = portf, type="risk", name="var", 
     risk_aversion=0.25)
```

---

```
opt_qu <- optimize.portfolio(R=matx.df, portfolio = qu, optimize_method = 
"ROI", trace=TRUE) print(opt_qu)
```

when i print `qu` which should have two objectives, it shows only the minvar, i.e., second objective only. How to add max return and min variance both.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `qu` instead of `portf` as a portfolio argument when adding second objective.

```
qu <- add.objective(portfolio = qu, type="risk", name="var", 
 risk_aversion=0.25)
```